# python cli-app: how to handle asynch process asking for user input?

Tags: python-3.x, command-line

I have a python cli application that updates remotes repositories with git.
Updates are done by starting asynchronous processses in a loop, so that each process doesn't wait the previous one to terminate.

But if it's a private repository, it will ask for a password, and I need a way to either:

- terminate process that is stuck with an input prompt, or
- pause the loop and don't start other processes until input has been handled

How can I do that?

Functions that add the process to the list:

```py
    def update(self):
        self.process = self.async_shell('git pull --ff-only')
        PROCESSING.append(self)
        if not ASYNC:
            wait(self)

    def async_shell(self, cmd):
        """Run a shell command asynchronously."""
        return subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), cwd=self.path,
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Function that work out the process list:

```py
def process_asynch(packdir=None, subdir=None):
    """Handle asynch package processing."""
    update = ACTION == 'update'
    start = time()
    while ( PROCESSING ):
        i = 0

        # --------------------

        for pack in PROCESSING:
            if TIMEOUT and pack.timeout < 0:
                warn_timeout(pack.name)
                pack.process.terminate()
                del PROCESSING[i]
                break
            if pack.process.poll() is not None:
                cmd = pack.process.communicate()
                cmd = [cmd[0].decode('utf-8'), cmd[1].decode('utf-8')]
                if packdir:
                    # output is managed by Packdir class
                    packdir.output(pack.output(cmd, updating=update), subdir)
                else:
                    # query for single packs, no Packdir calls
                    log(pack.output(cmd, updating=update))
                pack.helptags()
                del PROCESSING[i]
                break
            if TIMEOUT:
                passed = time() - start
                pack.timeout -= passed
                start += passed
            i += 1

        # --------------------

        if ( PROCESSING ):
            sleep(0.2)
```